# Google Places Autocomplete in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

Any one have wrapper in ASP.NET for Google Places Autocomplete API?
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html

Samples or approach is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the link of demo... for google places autocomplete...

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html

right click in browser and view page source... you can find approach....how to do it....

related Document.. find from here...

http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/

Comment: Please, check out... and give me comment.. if you find. any problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Google's API v3, they show an example that includes this snipped:

```
      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, in ASP.NET one needs to use the format document.getElementById("<%= controlname.ClientID %>")

How to create the syntax in the fillInAddress() above to pass the 'component' object and create the correct syntax to make this work?  Thanks